# Autoloading not working

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm just trying out Fat-Free Framework and I come to some trouble.
I try to use the autoloading to load one of my routes, like this :

```
<?php
$f3 = require 'vendor/bcosca/fatfree-core/base.php';

$f3->set('DEBUG', 3);

$f3->set('AUTOLOAD', 'app/');

$f3->config('app/routes.ini');

$f3->run();
```

I have a app/ dir, and a routes.ini file in it, like this :

```
[routes]
GET / = Test->show
```

Then, I have a Test.php file in app/, with this in it :

```
<?php
class Test {

    function show($f3) {
        echo 'ok !';
    }

}
```

After running this I get a big fancy error saying the following :

```
Method Not Allowed

HTTP 405 (GET /)
```

Any ideas ? (It isn't my PHP Version, if you'd ask yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code is fine. It's just that your Test class conflicts with the framework's own [Test](http://fatfreeframework.com/test) class.

Rename it to anything else and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried some things. This actually works :
The index.php file is the same as before.
The app/ dir now has a controllers/ dir in it.
There is a file named index.php inside the controllers dir, with this in it :

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

class Index {

    public function get() {
        echo 'Yey !';
    }

}
```

The routes file now looks like this :

```
[routes]
GET / = Controllers\Index->get
```

And that's it ! It works.